# How can I sort a second STL list by the order of first STL list

Tags: c++, stl

If I push back several fruits name to a first STL list, at the same time, I push back the number of each fruit into a second STL list;
If I want to sort the first STL list by alphabetical order, how can I sort the second STL list by the order of fruit STL list?

Comment: You can provide a custom function to all sort functions. Also, you can provide an object behaving like a function, where you can introduce the according ordering.

Comment: If the properties need to be connected together, as the fruit name and number are in this example, it doesn't make sense to store them in separate lists. Put them both into an object and store the object in a single list. Otherwise this becomes a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

> Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare.

Or you [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) afterwards one list of name+amount [pairs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) with a custom compare function (`std::string` supports [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)).

Comment: I know how to use map to do that, I am just wondering how to use stl list.

Comment: @HaotianSong So I guess you have to implements your own sort function which apply every operation from list containing fruit to the second one. But I agree with Youka and MarkRansom : std::list is not for what you want to do. If you really need a list of fruit, you can at choice : create a struct with a list of fruit and a map to make link between fruit and quantity, or extract a list according key of map